# JADE - Autocompile Jade files when I make changes at the included files (@include)

Tags: sass, pug, batch-processing

I'm using JADE and SASS on Atom.

---

On SASS you can use `// main: base.sass` (it's part of an atom plugin called: sass-autocompile) as a first line comment, in order to keep the "parent" file updated when you change the "children" files using (@import).
That way, each time you make a change on a sass file, it recompiles the "parent" file.

---

Is there any way, to do the same, or something similar, with JADE? I have so many pages with common content and it's quite frustrating having to re-compile all of the files on each change.
Here is an example of my code:

### Child Jade File:

```
.navbar
  ul
    li: a(href="#") Home
    li: a(href="#") About
    li: a(href="#") Blog
    li: a(href="#") Contact
```

### Parent Jade File:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    include head/head.jade
  body
    include head/navbar.jade
    include main/top.jade
    include main/middle.jade
    include main/bottom.jade

    include footer/footer
```

Each time I make a tiny change on navbar.jade file, I have to recompile over 40 jade files one by one.